# Component identification in a thermal device

Tags: identification, components, thermal

I have a picture of a device's handpiece and I want to know the applicatioan of its components but I'm confused about one of them.

Can anyone help me to figure out what this is component? (Marked with a red rectangle in the picture.)

[image]

Comment: there is printing on the component ... why is that information not included in your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a thermal fuse for safety. It cuts power to something when that thermal fuse heats above the limit.